# How do I prevent git re-generating diff?

Tags: git

(I'm not sure about the title, someone please help edit it to a more appropriate one.)

Git automatically generates the minimal diff, which is good for storage but I really don't mind wasting one or two lines for a better readability.

With my coding style, the diff that git automatically generates often treats closing brace of different blocks with same indent as unchanged. For example:

```
-if (true) {
-   // Do something
+foreach (int i in array) {
+   // Do something else
 }
```

This could lead to a diff really difficult to read when there's more modifications around. I'd want it to just look like this:

```
-if (true) {
-   // Do something
-}
+foreach (int i in array) {
+   // Do something else
+}
```

Basically remove old lines, then add new lines, if there's "unchanged" lines in between (empty lines, closing braces, and other common lines like `} else {`) just remove them as well and add them in new lines accordingly.

So I tried to use `git add file --patch` and manually changed it to my desire, but after closing the editor, git reverts my changes to the original minimal diff (with closing brace unchanged)

Is it possible to achieve what I want without creating two separate commits?

Comment: Yes, but you'd have to modify the source code of `diff`.

Comment: For what it's worth, Git doesn't use diff for packing files at all. It uses a binary delta format inside pack files. Loose (unpacked) objects are not deltified, they are merely zlib-compressed. What you see when you run `git diff` is computed temporarily *by* `git diff`, then thrown away again.

Comment: Well... I completely got that wrong. Now I know that git doesn't store diff at all, what I'm really looking for is a better "diff generator". Maybe it's better off just write separate commits for deletion/addition.

Comment: You probably want some kind of syntax-aware diff tool, and then use `git difftool` instead.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't think this is possible because the lines containing the closing braces do not differ. Your diff would need to be able to understand your code to know that since the opening block is different, the closing block should also be included in the hunk. There *might* be a diff tool out there which can do that, and if you can find it you can make `git diff` use it as an external diff helper with `git diff --ext-diff`. [The Git Book has examples of changing the behavior of `git diff` using git attributes](https://git-scm.com/book/en/v2/Customizing-Git-Git-Attributes).

---

You might get the clarity you want using a visual diff tool and looking at the changes side-by-side. You can do this with `git difftool` and it will launch an external diff viewer. For example, here's what your change looks like using [Meld](http://meldmerge.org/). Meld is pretty primitive, but there are many other tools out there like it and `git difftool` knows how to use many of them once they're installed.

[image]

Many code editors and IDEs will have their own built in visual diff tool that will give you the same clarity. Here's the [split-diff package](https://atom.io/packages/split-diff) for the [Atom editor](https://atom.io/).

[image]